# Помогите с pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Всё уже перепробовал. Можете сказать в чём заключается ошибка? Нужно установить на python3.4, раньше устанавливалось, а сейчас уже нет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Оставляейте ваш код (на будущее) и ошибки в текстовом формате, а не в картинках.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller поддерживает Python 3.6 или новее.

Comment: А чем можно собрать exe файл на python3.4?

Comment: Напишите более подробный ответ, с указанием источников вашего утверждения, возможные способы решения или альтернативы.

Comment: тут вариантов не много, но есть вопрос, почему именно Python 3.4? А так в принципе поищи в интернете, попробуй, вот две ссылки где о этом что-либо написано: https://pylab.ru/how-to-create-exe-in-python/ , https://habr.com/ru/company/vdsina/blog/557316/

Comment: @Proga мне нет необходимости, а вот если кто другой встретится с такой же проблемой может легко благодаря вам найти ответ. И вы сможете поднять рейтинг составляя хорошие ответы, что даст вам больше возможностей на данном ресурсе